# Shows "Uninstalling old version..." message when starting debugging on VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I didn't get "Uninstalling old version..." message in the last few days, I don't know if it's related but I got a notification on VSCode that there's new update on flutter and after that I always got that message.

I already did try this command

```
flutter clean
```

and It doesn't work but when running this command

```
flutter run
```

on terminal It won't show that message.

Comment: did you remove old apk from your device or emulator ?

Comment: @AR Yes. also the app has the same version on my pubspec.yaml